# Bind and Unbind functions using JQuery in Sharepoint Application Page 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am new to Sharepoint. Now i am creating Application Page. My question is, i have a scroll function of 's4-workspace'. My jquery Vesion jquery-1.7.2.min.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#s4-workspace').bind('scroll', function () {
             alert("Called");
         });
})
```

My unbind code :

```
$('#s4-workspace').unbind('scroll');
```

But when i bind the same function it's not woking, Code is

```
$('#s4-workspace').bind('scroll');
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: `$('#s4-workspace').bind('scroll');` you are missing the handler: `$('#s4-workspace').bind('scroll',handler);` where handler is the function you want to call

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for reply, please mention the handler, i am a beginner in jquery

Comment: "where handler is the function you want to call"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the handler every time you bind. Since it looks like you want to bind/unbind multiple times, I would create a named function:

```
function scrollHandler(e) {
    alert('called');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#s4-workspace').bind('scroll', scrollHandler);
});
```

Then later:

```
$('#s4-workspace').unbind('scroll');
```

And even later:

```
$('#s4-workspace').bind('scroll', scrollHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks For Reply, it's working. But when binding (re-binding), the function scrollHandler is automatically called. is there any way to avoid the scrollHandler function call

Comment: Are you doing `.bind('scroll', scrollHandler());` instead of `.bind('scroll', scrollHandler);` ?

Comment: no my code is $('#s4-workspace').bind('scroll', ScrollHandler);

Comment: Hm, I haven't seen that behavior before. I would guess that a scroll event is being triggered for some reason. Can you reproduce the issue at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: yes i wrote a code for move to scroll to particular control in page, thats only i am unbind the scroll event before the code called

Comment: My Code is :

$('#s4-workspace').unbind('scroll');
$('#s4-workspace').scrollTop((my_element.offset().top));
$('#s4-workspace').bind('scroll', ScrollHandler);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#s4-workspace').bind('scroll',function(){
    //code here
 });
```